# How to send trailing metadata from python gRPC service to grpc-web client?

Tags: javascript, python, envoyproxy, grpc-web

I'm trying to send trailing metadata from python gRPC service to grpc-web client. But on client side I cannot receive it.

I'm using envoy proxy server to connect grpc-web with python gRPC service.

For sending metadata I'm using this method:

```py
class Greeter(helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterServicer):
    def SayHello(self, request, context):
        context.set_trailing_metadata((
            ('checksum', 'I agree'),
            ('retry', 'false'),
        ))
        return helloworld_pb2.HelloReply(message='Hello, %s!' % request.name)
```

On client I'm trying to access metadata this way:

```js
var call = greeterService.sayHello(request, {}, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.code);
    console.log(err.message);
  } else {
    console.log(response.getMessage());
  }
});
call.on('status', function(status) {
  console.log(status.code);
  console.log(status.details);
  console.log(status.metadata); // here should arrive metadata
});
```

I'm sending it how it is described in documentation. But metadata is not arrived.

Did anybody have such problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling method [`set_trailing_metadata`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html?highlight=set_trailing_metadata#grpc.ServicerContext.set_trailing_metadata), you need to call [`send_initial_metadata`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html?highlight=send_initial_metadata#grpc.ServicerContext.send_initial_metadata) with same medatdata keys but any values.

In my case it will looks like this:

```py
class Greeter(helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterServicer):
    def SayHello(self, request, context):
        context.send_initial_metadata((
            ('checksum', ''),
            ('retry', ''),
        ))
        context.set_trailing_metadata((
            ('checksum', 'I agree'),
            ('retry', 'false'),
        ))
        return helloworld_pb2.HelloReply(message='Hello, %s!' % request.name)
```

Actually I found this solution accidentally.

I assume that you need to specify **headers names** in initial metadata and only then you should set **headers values** in trailing metadata and then envoy could pack it properly and deliver via HTTP 1.1.

Comment: This is causing timeout for me. Do you have any other solution of setting data.